# Losing queries in pgAdmin after pressing backspace when the focus is outside the query editor

Tags: pgadmin

While writing a complex query in `pgAdmin` (installed version: 4.24) with the `Query Tool`, it happened many times that I pressed backspace on my keyboard while the focus was outside the query editor, for instance on the `Query Editor` and `Query History` toolbar. This oddly listed the server explorer within the query editor and made me lose the query itself without a remedy. I ended up with a somewhat smaller `pgAdmin` inside the query editor window, with no way obvious to me of getting the query back.

Is there a fix to this odd behaviour?